# Best way to get all info from a bridge table

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

this is my scenario, I have 3 tables linked in 1 bridge table

[image]

The propose of the query that I try to create is to have the data in this order

```cs
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public List<Project> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class Project
{
    public int ProjectId { get; set; }

    public List<Right> Rights { get; set; }
}

public class Right
{
    public int RightId { get; set; }
}
```

This is an example of data inside the database
[image]

I want to avoid the for loop like this

```cs
var query1 = (from ac in _contextView.AccessProject
            group ac by new { ac.OramsUserId } into acGroup
            select new User()
            {
                UserId = acGroup.Key.OramsUserId,
                Projects = (from y in acGroup.ToList()
                        select new Project(){
                            ProjectId = y.ProjectId
                        }).Distinct().ToList()
            }
            ).ToList();

foreach (var item in query1)
{
    foreach (var p in item.Projects)
    {

        var rights = (from ac in _contextView.AccessProject
                        where ac.OramsUserId == item.UserId
                        && ac.ProjectId == p.ProjectId
                        select new Right()
                        {
                            RightId = ac.RightOnProjectId
                        }).ToList();
        p.Rights == rights;
    }
}
```

Can anyone recommend a better way to write this query? or a more elegant way of writing the query.
I would like to get the user object with the lists inside in only one query.

Also, Can anyone recommend me a course to better understand queries via linq?

**UPDATE**

Here I list the models of the 4 tables

```
    public partial class Project
    {
        public Project()
        {
            AccessProject = new HashSet<AccessProject>();
            SensorsAssignedToProject = new HashSet<SensorsAssignedToProject>();
        }

        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// user table id, indicates who is the creator of the project
        /// </summary>
        public int CreatorId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// longitude for dashboard map
        /// </summary>
        public decimal? Longitude { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// latitude for dashboard map
        /// </summary>
        public decimal? Latitude { get; set; }
        public bool IsEnable { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<AccessProject> AccessProject { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<SensorsAssignedToProject> SensorsAssignedToProject { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public partial class RightOnProject
    {
        public RightOnProject()
        {
            AccessProject = new HashSet<AccessProject>();
        }

        public int RightOnProjectId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// field for the match in the orams system 3
        /// </summary>
        public string RightDescription { get; set; } = null!;
        /// <summary>
        /// display on the web page
        /// </summary>
        public string RightVisualization { get; set; } = null!;

        public virtual ICollection<AccessProject> AccessProject { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public partial class OramsUser
    {
        public OramsUser()
        {
            AccessMeasuringPoint = new HashSet<AccessMeasuringPoint>();
            AccessProject = new HashSet<AccessProject>();
        }

        public int OramsUserId { get; set; }
        public string OramsUsername { get; set; } = null!;
        public string OramsPassword { get; set; } = null!;
        public string Email { get; set; } = null!;
        public long? TelegramId { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; } = null!;
        public string FirstName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string LastName { get; set; } = null!;
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        public bool EanbleUser { get; set; }

        public virtual Role Role { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual ICollection<AccessMeasuringPoint> AccessMeasuringPoint { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<AccessProject> AccessProject { get; set; }
    }
```

```
    public partial class AccessProject
    {
        public int AccessProjectId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// fk table orams user
        /// </summary>
        public int OramsUserId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// fk table project
        /// </summary>
        public int ProjectId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// fk table right on project table
        /// </summary>
        public int RightOnProjectId { get; set; }
        public DateTime GrantDate { get; set; }

        public virtual OramsUser OramsUser { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual Project Project { get; set; } = null!;
        public virtual RightOnProject RightOnProject { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

Comment: Instead of posting database tables images, post Model classes. It will help to understand your navigation properties.

Comment: Hi, done. I hope it's clearer in that way

Answer (score 1):

This query better to separate on two parts - retrieving data and combining on the client side:

```cs
// retrieving from database only needed fields
var flatQuery = 
    from u in _contextView.OramsUser
    from ap in u.AccessProject
    select new
    {
        UserId = u.OramsUserId,
        ProjectId = ap.ProjectId,
        RightId = ap.RightOnProjectId 
    };

// generating result
var result = flatQuery
    .ToList() // materialize objects
    .GroupBy(r => r.UserId)
    .Select(g => new User
    {
        UserId = g.Key,
        Projects = g
            .GroupBy(x => x.ProjectId)
            .Select(pg => new Project
            {
                ProjectId = pg.Key,
                Rights = pg
                    .Select(x => new Right { RightId = x.RightId })
                    .ToList()
            })
            .ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I couldn't figure out how to make a group by inside another. 
I ask you for one last favor
Can you recommend any resources to improve with this type of query, In general with all queries (but avoiding the classic tutorial for newbies)

Comment: I can't. It's just ten years of experience. Grouping is weak part of SQL translation and if you need items instead of aggregation - better to do that on client-side.

Comment: thanks anyway. I will follow your advice. have a nice day.